# Change History Time Azure Communication Services

Tags: c#, azure-communication-services

I'm trying to create a simple chat app using Azure Communication Services SDK for .NET.
I managed to add participants to a thread following

[this example](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Communication.Chat/1.1.0/index.html).
I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-communication-chat/azure.communication.chat.chatparticipant?view=azure-python) for class `ChatParticipant` and I found out that it can show the time from which the chat history is shared with the participant. The default date is 1/1/1970 00:00. 
I would like to make this date variable, so that a user can only see messages from the moment he joined the chat on. 
Is there a way to do it? 
 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to set the property for **ShareHistoryTime** at the time of adding a participant to the Chat thread?. e.g in the below example, it is set to current time.

```
// ThreadId : Chat ThreadId , participantUserId : participant communication user Identifier 

ChatThreadClient chatThreadClient = 
chatClient.GetChatThreadClient(ThreadId);
chatThreadClient.AddParticipant(new ChatParticipant(
       new CommunicationUserIdentifier(participantUserId))
       {
                DisplayName = displayName,
                ShareHistoryTime = DateTimeOffset.Now
       });
```

You can refer Chat Participant Properties [here](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Communication.Chat/1.1.0/index.html#add-thread-participants)